# How to remove spaces from a serialized string for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var queryString = $('#formname').serialize();
$.post(queryString, function(data) { ...
```

Request URL sometimes becomes

> http:\domain.com\page.php?parm=1&contr y=2&...

how to remove the space in the text of country?
I had tried

```
 queryString.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

and

```
.trim
```

but no success..

Thanks,

Comment: Change the name of your form field instead. It may be a bug in your code which causes the name to contain a space.

Comment: tried also (http:\domain.com\page.php?parm=1&contr y=2&...).replace(/\s/g, ''), same error

Answer (score 0):

`replace` works fine. Just **strings are immutable**, so you have to store or use directly the result of `replace` because **it won't update your variable**.

Quick note: this is kind of weird to have backslashes unescaped in your URL, but... eh, that's yours.

```js
const url = 'http:\domain.com\page.php?parm=1&contr y=2&...';

console.log(url.replace(/\s/g, ''));
console.log(url);
```

By the way, `trim` only removes outer spaces.

```js
const str = '   Hello World!    ';
console.log(str);
console.log(str.trim());
```

Comment: hello sjahan, Thanks for comment. I tried add console.log(url.replace(/\s/g, ''));
console.log(url); but now is ...count ry...

Comment: What? Mate, just click on the button `Run code snippet`, see it does work, that's it. It's a 3 lines sample script, there is no black magic here. Using `replace` with the given regex works.

Comment: sir, the code is work. But in my case, its really unusal. Every time I clean cache and run again, the space will appear in some other word, such as this time ...php?pa rm=1&...

Comment: @mos As I said, there is no black magic. Post more of your code so that we can reproduce your problem. Otherwise, we cannot help more than that. You want to remove spaces in a string, here it is. If it comes back, then show where and how.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using the trim () you can, the trim () removes unnecessary spaces

```
yourstring.trim()
```